# Most efficient way to find the number of possible unique fixed length permutations?

Tags: python, algorithm

I've got this dictionary:

```
num_dict = {
    (2, 3): [(2, 2), (4, 4), (4, 5)],
    (2, 2): [(2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)],
    (4, 5): [(4, 4)],
    (1, 0): [(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)],
    (4, 4): [(4, 5)],
    (1, 1): [(1, 0), (2, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)],
    }
```

I need to find the max number of 3 long combinations of the first values of each of these tuples, where only the values of each key can proceed said key.

My current code for finding all unique (3 long) combinations is this:

```
ans_set = set()
for x in num_dict:
    for y in num_dict[x]:
        for z in num_dict[y]:
            ans_set.add((x[0], y[0], z[0]))
return len(ans_set)
```

*This returns* `10` and `ans_set` ends up being:

```
{
 (2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2), (1, 4, 4),
 (2, 2, 4), (1, 1, 2), (4, 4, 4),
 (1, 2, 4), (1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 1),
 (2, 4, 4)
}
```

*But I don't actually care about what the sets are, just the number of them*

This method is not particularly efficient as it actually generates every possible combination and puts it in a set.

I don't need to know each unique combination, I just need to know how many there are.

I have a feeling this can be done, maybe using the lengths of the value lists? but I am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Clarifying questions about what I need are welcome as I realize I might not have explained it in the most clear fashion.

## Final Edit

I've found the best way to find the number of triples by reevaluating what i needed it to do. This method doesn't actually find the triples, it just counts them.

```
def foo(l):
    llen = len(l)
    total = 0
    cache = {}
    for i in range(llen):
        cache[i] = 0
    for x in range(llen):
        for y in range(x + 1, llen):
            if l[y] % l[x] == 0:
                cache[y] += 1
                total += cache[x]
    return total
```

And here's a version of the function that explains the thought process as it goes (not good for huge lists though because of spam prints):

```
def bar(l):
    list_length = len(l)
    total_triples = 0
    cache = {}
    for i in range(list_length):
        cache[i] = 0
    for x in range(list_length):
        print("\n\nfor index[{}]: {}".format(x, l[x]))
        for y in range(x + 1, list_length):
            print("\n\ttry index[{}]: {}".format(y, l[y]))
            if l[y] % l[x] == 0:
                print("\n\t\t{} can be evenly diveded by {}".format(l[y], l[x]))
                cache[y] += 1
                total_triples += cache[x]
                print("\t\tcache[{0}] is now {1}".format(y, cache[y]))
                print("\t\tcount is now {}".format(total_triples))
                print("\t\t(+{} from cache[{}])".format(cache[x], x))
            else:
                print("\n\t\tfalse")
    print("\ntotal number of triples:", total_triples)
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the sample output. It will help others in understanding the behavior of your code

Comment: @anonymous The dictionary is the input

Comment: But I asked about the *sample **out**put* based on the logic. just `10` is nt providing any clarity :)

Comment: OH, sorry about that. You want to see the content of `ans_set`?

Comment: Ran the code in my system, and got the required behavior (if your code is correct). It is good practice to explain the problem with examples, you'll get better response + will might get to know the issues with your code regarding which you are not aware of

Comment: I have one doubt with your implementation. Why `(x[0], y[0], z[0]))`. Do you want the combinations of only *first* index value in your tuple? I do not think that should be the case.

Comment: @anonymous yes I only need the number of unique combinations of the first item in the tuples, and having the whole tuple makes it such that the set doesn't filter out repeats.

Comment: I would make the dict only use the 1st items in the tuples, but then there would be keys with the same value and that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying that pairing up the first elements from each sublist match up to the keys in your dict? Your implementation and the current answer are completely different if not and yours would also error

Answer (score 1):

If i get you right:

```
from itertools import combinations

num_dict = {
    (2, 3): [(2, 2), (4, 4), (4, 5)],
    (2, 2): [(2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)],
    (4, 5): [(4, 4)],
    (1, 0): [(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)],
    (4, 4): [(4, 5)],
    (1, 1): [(1, 0), (2, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)]
    }
set(combinations([k[0] for k in num_dict.keys()], 3))
```

Output:

```
{(1, 4, 1),
 (2, 1, 1),
 (2, 1, 4),
 (2, 2, 1),
 (2, 2, 4),
 (2, 4, 1),
 (2, 4, 4),
 (4, 1, 1),
 (4, 1, 4),
 (4, 4, 1)}
```

And `len()` is `10`

So basically what you're would do, make all combinations with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), from first elements of dict keys with a length 3 and then get `set` to eliminate repeating elements.

**UPDATE**

Since you updated the question with desired output data

You can do the following

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
list(combinations_with_replacement(set([k[0] for k in num_dict.keys()]), 3))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 4),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 4, 4),
 (2, 2, 2),
 (2, 2, 4),
 (2, 4, 4),
 (4, 4, 4)]
```

**UPD2**

So about time consumption i've ran it

```
num_dict = {
    (2, 3): [(2, 2), (4, 4), (4, 5)],
    (2, 2): [(2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)],
    (4, 5): [(4, 4)],
    (1, 0): [(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)],
    (4, 4): [(4, 5)],
    (1, 1): [(1, 0), (2, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)]
    }
def a(num_dict):
    ans_set = set()
    for x in num_dict:
        for y in num_dict[x]:
            for z in num_dict[y]:
                ans_set.add((x[0], y[0], z[0]))
    return len(ans_set)
def b(num_dict):
    from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
    return len(list(combinations_with_replacement(set([k[0] for k in num_dict.keys()]), 3)))
%timeit a(num_dict)
%timeit b(num_dict)
```

And the the results are:

```
The slowest run took 4.90 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.1 µs per loop

The slowest run took 5.37 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.77 µs per loop
```

So solution that i've presented here is 2x times faster.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this isn't actually any faster... sorry.

Comment: @ElliotRoberts i've added also time consumption in the answer with your and mine approach

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I guess I overestimated my code / underestimated whoever made itertools. Thanks for figuring it out!

Comment: Wait... `combinations_with_replacement()` returns an itertools object, not a list of combinations.

Comment: @ElliotRoberts yes, you're right, but who is stopping you from converting it to `list` object as i did?